# Difference between `next` and `:_next`

Tags: ruby

Due to my other requirement, I was searching another symbols with the line `p( Symbol.all_symbols )`. At that time, I also got `:_next` in my IRB, but had no idea about it. I am using:

```
C:\>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15) [i386-mingw32]
```

You can check the same with the code below:

```
Arr = Symbol.all_symbols 
Arr.include?(:_next) #=> true
```

Could anyone help me understand how `next` differs functionally from `:_next`?

Comment: What's the context? `:_next` is a symbol object.

Comment: Actually wanted to see what `_next` does? when to use?

Comment: next can be a method, but :_next is a symbol for sure.

Comment: `_next` does nothing in my Rails console. What context are you working in?

Comment: I did `p( Symbol.all_symbols )` to find another symbol and beside I got `:_next`. Thus asked here if anyone familiarized with it. Because I do know about `next` but never `:_next`.

Comment: You did any other work in IRB before running your command? The symbol may simply get defined in passing in a piece of code in one or more Ruby libraries, and have no use other than the work it does in that library code.

Comment: After your comment I closed my IRB multiple times and used the above code accordingly. I got every time `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol does not normally exist.

But with your code you create it .. just by mentioning it.

Try in irb:

```
arr = Symbol.all_symbols
arr.include? :_next                       # => false
arr = Symbol.all_symbols
arr.include? :_next                       # => true
```

Or (with a new instance) try this:

```
Symbol.all_symbols.map(&:to_s).include?('_next') # => false
:_next
Symbol.all_symbols.map(&:to_s).include?('_next') # => true
```

Comment: in My case I am getting the `true` in my first attempt. I don't know why not the same with you. :(

Answer (score 0):

`next` is a Ruby method, `:_next` is a symbol.

Suppose you have an array = `[1,2,3]`. Running the below command will print [2, 6]

```
[1,2,3].each{ |n| next if n.even? ; puts 2*n }
```

`next` as a symbol converts the receiver to a String, then returns the result of String#next as a Symbol.

Example: `"gender".to_sym.next` will return `:gendes`

Comment: Can you provide an example for that last line?

Comment: `:_next` - what this does?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't use the `_next` symbol that shows up in the console when you run `Symbol.all_symbols`. It's just a point of curiosity, but dang am I curious now.

Comment: i duno but definitely it's a symbol :)

Comment: Humm... Let's see who can answer this...actually you know in ruby symbols can be method or variables too.. :) but what is `:_next` ? this is my question I also never happened to see this before. Hope anyone out there will definitely would have answers of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have now tested this in ruby 1.9.3-p374, ruby 1.9.3-p385, ruby 1.9.3-p392 and ruby 2.0.0-p0 on my Mac. I'm not able to reproduce this. I always get false.

Have you tried it on any other versions of Ruby?

Comment: I am using window-7 only. I do have only the version I mentioned in my post. So I can't test. But the other users as above confirmed that they got in their `IRB` too.

Comment: What version of IRB are you using?

Comment: `C:\>irb --version
irb 0.9.6(09/06/30)`